# What is the proper way to select a new version of the kernel and boot into it in Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: boot, kernel, raspberrypi

I know that in Ubuntu the regular way of selecting the kernel version to boot can be done through grub. How do I do this in Ubuntu for Raspberry pi? I guess it is using uboot, should I configure it somehow?

I find myself in need of testing more versions of the kernel to find a bug that is affecting the system, so a quick way would be useful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a specific kernel version from the repos (for example 5.8.0-1016), install it first:

```
sudo apt install linux-raspi-headers-5.8.0-1016 linux-image-5.8.0-1016-raspi linux-headers-5.8.0-1016-raspi linux-modules-5.8.0-1016-raspi linux-headers-5.8.0-1016-raspi
```

then enable it with the command:

```
sudo flash-kernel --force 5.8.0-1016-raspi
```

this is reverted if an update to the kernel is installed afterwards.